# How to play wave data from UDP message (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, udp, audio-streaming, naudio

I have an app which is receiving wave data (PCM raw data) via network through UDP port.
How can I set up to play received wave data using Naudio.
I have tried to find with google and read some stuff related to Naudio documentation, but so far haven't any success.
Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that with UDP there is no guarantee that you will receive packets at all, or in the order in which they were sent. You could roll your own packet sequencing code, but it would be easier to use TCP/IP. You may be able to "get away with" using UDP over a LAN however. Ideally you should also detect when you run out of buffered data and pass "silence" data into the audio system so that lack of buffered data doesn't lead to the awful stuttering that most audio/CD players do, but simply pauses playback until real data is available once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NAudioDemo application demonstrates how to do this in the Network Chat demo. You use the `BufferedWaveProvider` to store the decompressed audio as it arrives, and use that to feed WaveOut. you might also want to automatically pause if there is not enough buffered audio, to prevent stuttering playback.

Comment: Hi Mark, first of all thank you for wonderful library. I have already downloaded the source code for Network Chat demo, Mp3 Streaming Demo and now I am trying to understand the things, but as I am new in .net and audio programing it is a little bit complicated to understand whole staff. So thank you for your hints they are valuable for me. May you have some more simple example of Network Streaming or some other simple program example?

Answer (score 2):

Well I did some work on this nAudio stuff long back and am sorry I might not be of much help as I am afraid I hardly remember it...

But I think there was something like WaveOut Class and a WaveStream which contained your WAV data and you call Play on the WaveOut class after associating it with WaveStream.

Try give a look to this WavOut class you might get some clues, also I was quite new to this Audio world when I worked on that and my approach was to take their sample program that plays a wav file and see how they are doing it...that was how I figured out what needs to be done....

Good Luck...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already downloaded some examples where staff like WaveOut and a WaveStream are used, but they didn't much related to my case. In any case thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

UDP Stream  --> buffer --> NAudio WaveStream

First, check that the source PCM audio can be played correctly by NAudio. Do this "offline", before sending it via a socket.

I will do some research and post some code later.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have already extracted the data from UDP message and store it in the array. But I couldn't connect this buffer to Naudio. I am a new in this area and I would be grateful if you will post some code example.